# newbie in jquery - jquery pop up

Tags: jquery

I see this nice jquery plugin here: [prettyphoto jquery lightbox](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/) is there any way to achieve like this with a simple jquery only.

I only need is to pop up and Inline content. your reply is big help.

if you can show demonstration in fiddle or something i appreciate!

Comment: you could use jQuery UI, http://jqueryui.com however, that's another library, so it's technically not "simple jquery" but jquery none the less.  look up `$(selector).dialog();`

Comment: It's not really very 'simple', but you can make your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dJ7Wj/2/). Mostly I did the work using `jquery`.

You can start from that.

Hope it helps.

UPDATE:

I have updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dJ7Wj/3/). But some `css` properties should be set in the `jquery` for it to work.

Comment: hi sir i see the code sir and it seems i like the way it is! is there way css code separately

Comment: Yes, just add class names to the `overlay`, `closeBtn`, `popupWrapper` and `popup`. Then migrate the css inside `.css()` to the css file. Actually I've already put the class for `popupWrapper` but I didn't use it.

Comment: i try to edit your code. separate the css from jquery but its not working. thank you anyway for the time. I try again... hope I can get it!

Comment: Remember that in the code the `top` and `left` values for the `wrapper` is calculated, It should be in the `jquery`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a simple "dialog" SimpleModal might be about right: http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

It's not a "lightbox" plugin per se, but it's a lot lighter than adding jQuery UI. Seems fairly simple, too:

```
$("#your-element-id").modal();
```

You could use this for text, images, forms, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to use jQuery UI dialogs. http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Ofcourse a pure solution would be to define the lightbox in css, populate it with jQuery and show it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQueryUI dialog,

simple implementation like the following [jqueryui demo](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#dialog").dialog();
}); 

<div id="dialog" style="display:none">
    <div>
        Your Dialog content
    </div>
</div>
```